# TPLink USB Wifi Adapter needs replugging after every Boot / Reboot

Tags: wireless, usb, adapter

I need help with my TP Link USB wifi adapter.

I have been unplugging and replugging my USB wifi adapter after every boot to get it to recognize.

Any tips to let it work automatically on every boot or reboot?

```
$ sudo lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Logs:

[image: Screenshot of Logs]

- TP Link USB wifi adapter
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Thanking in advance..

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the output of `sudo lsusb`? This will show some device-specific information about your USB devices, making it easier to suggest solutions. If you see any information about the TPLink adapter in the `/var/log/syslog` file, that would also be very helpful to see why Ubuntu is not auto-starting the device 

Comment: thanks bro.. i have already updated my question. Appreciate your help

Comment: That WiFi device is [really hit-or-miss with Ubuntu 20.04](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0bda-8179) due to the state of the drivers. There are some alternate drivers available, [such as this one](https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus) but I cannot vouch for the quality or completeness of the code 

Comment: When you boot, is the needed driver loaded? `lsmod | grep r81` Does the wireless start if you load it explicitly? `sudo modprobe r8188eu` ?

Comment: lsmod | grep r81
r8188eu               421888  0
lib80211               16384  1 r8188eu
cfg80211              888832  1 r8188eu

Comment: i dont know what it means... tried sudo modprobe r8188eu  , still need to re-plug the usb wifi adapter to get it working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, i would like to thank matigo and chili555 for the tips and suggestions. Appreciate it a lot.

So i decided to get a better usb wifi dongle made by Asus (ASUS USB-AC53)

I followed the steps given by Wayne Khan @ the link below :

https://waynekhan.github.io/2020/05/30/asus-usb-ac53-nano-ubuntu.html

Now everything works like a charm. The usb wifi adapter works after booting and reboot too..

Thanks Guys